# Java JNI symbol lookup error

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

First of all, I am new to JNI. I have a java class that imports native function, here's `Java` code:

```
public static native byte[] sha512(byte[] message);
static {
    System.loadLibrary("sha512");
}
```

And when I try to call the function in java I got following error:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /home/kgb/IdeaProjects/JavaCiphersLib/out/production/JavaCiphersLib/libsha512.so: undefined symbol: _Znam
```

Here's `C++` header file which is generated using `javah`:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class my_SHA512 */

#ifndef _Included_my_SHA512
#define _Included_my_SHA512
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     my_SHA512
 * Method:    sha512
 * Signature: ([B)[B
 */
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_my_SHA512_sha512
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Here's implementation:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "my_SHA512.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_my_SHA512_sha512(JNIEnv* env, jclass _class, jbyteArray message)
{
    unsigned char* msg = new unsigned char[5];
    delete msg;

    printf("Test Test Test\n");
    return message;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now, if I remove `unsigned char* msg = new unsigned char[5];` line the error's gone. Here's what `c++filt` says:

```
kgb@KGB-PC:~$ c++filt -n _Znam
operator new[](unsigned long)
```

Here's how I compiled the c++ code:

```
gcc -I$JAVA_INC_PATH -I$JAVA_INC_PATH./linux -fPIC -c my_SHA512Impl.cpp
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsha512.so.2 -o libsha512.so.2.0 my_SHA512Impl.o
```

So how I get rid of the error? And it'd be great if you give some explanation of how all that c++ magic works and how to avoid such errors in the future.
Thanks in advance.

**UPD**
Don't know it's useful, but here's `ldd libsha512.so` output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd29171000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0e1cd86000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0e1d34d000)
```

Comment: It sometimes helps to simply use **g++** instead of **gcc**

Comment: Wow, that helped! Thanks! Please consider make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sometimes helps to simply use **g++** instead of **gcc**, because it adds the C++ runtime libraries by default.